# openpyxl writing multiple headers and content inside the same sheet

Tags: python, django, csv, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl for the first time in my django project. I got the task to make a two-part excel, that should be looking approximately like this:

[image]

So basically i want to show all users of a certain organization. This is what I have done so far:

```
def export_organisation(self, org_id):
        organization = Organization.objects.get(pk=org_id)

        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws.title = "OKR"

        headers = [
            ['Organisation Name', 'Signup Date', 'Language'],
            ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email']
        ]

        line = 1  # Start from the first row

        for header_row in headers:

            ws.append(header_row)

            # Format bold the cells in the first row
            ft_bold = Font(bold = True)
            for cell in ws[ws.max_row]:
                cell.font = ft_bold
                
        line = ws.max_row+1

        ws['A' + str(line)] = organization.name
        ws['B' + str(line)] = organization.signup_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        ws['C' + str(line)] = organization.language

        

        for user in organization.users.all():

            ws['D' + str(line)] = user.first_name
            ws['E' + str(line)] = user.last_name
            ws['F' + str(line)] = user.email
            line+=1
        
        # Filename with team name and date
        wb.save('{}.xlsx'.format(org_id))
```

But this gives me following output:

[image]

Is there a way to make it look like the first image? If yes, what did I miss?

Comment: The two images look the same to me.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i updated the screen shot

Comment: So specifically what is your problem? Yes, you want the spreadsheet to look like the second screenshot. Your code (I assume it's yours) writes certain values to cells at various coordinates already, and makes some cells bold. Just change your code so it writes them to the correct coordinates.

Comment: That is the question. I've tried to change the code but is still ends up like the first picture. What about the code is wrong?